# magento 2 how to redirect disabled product to category page?

Tags: product, category, magento2.2, seo, 301-redirect

I want to redirect disabled products to the related category page. I have tried discontinued option which is available in admin but it is not working.

[image]

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: The way you are following is the right one. Try to clear the cache or open in a private browser to see if the change has happen.

Comment: Do you using anyb extension ?

Comment: @AmitBera, I am not using any extension.